# Calcular porcentaje de cumplimiento

Tags: sql, matemáticas

Poniendo en contexto, tengo un software donde los usuarios montan solicitudes y un personal se encarga de solucionarlas, en una tabla tengo el tiempo que el personal tardo en cerrar dicha solicitud y el tiempo máximo que debió haber tardado, poniendo un ejemplo; cerro la solicitud en 10 horas y el máximo eran 32.

Lo que necesito es calcular una especie de porcentaje de cumplimiento, si cerro la solicitud en 1 hora  y el máximo eran 32 entonces tiene un 100% y este vaya bajando con forme las horas de cierre vayan subiendo, por ejemplo, si se demoro 32 horas en cerrar la solicitud y el máximo era de 32 entonces el cumplimiento que sea de 1% o de 0% y a partir de eso sea negativo, si se demoro 40 horas y el máximo era 32 entonces que sea por ejemplo -8%.

necesito la formula mas que otra cosa, agradezco sus respuestas!

Comment: Debes poner lo que has intentado, edita tu pregunta y pon lo que tienes hasta ahora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El porcentaje es `1 - (tiempo_que_tarda_en_resolver/tiempo_max_para_resolver)`.

De esta forma, si se tarda más que el máximo permitido verás un número negativo.

Ten en cuenta que esta fórmula expresa el porcentaje de tiempo que dejó disponible el operador al realizar la tarea.